# Where could I find a Chespin or a Froakie?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Where do you find a Chespin and a Froakie in Pokemon Y?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you started with Fennekin.

When you beat the Elite Four you will obtain a Chespin from your rival, and in order to get a Froakie, you will have to either:

1. Trade
2. Catch a Frogadier from the Friend Safari and then breed to get a froakie